# Calling a specific id inside a frame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a iframe tag in mainpage.html, that iframe calls back.html..

is there any way to call only the specific ids in back.html for display in iframe..

Detail:
I have 25x25 table in back.html. initially iframe shows all 625 cells minimised. each cell has a unique id. can i call a specific cell only to display(original size) inside iframe.

or is there any other way to go around it.. please specify

Comment: Show us the relevant HTML.  I have absolutely no idea what you're asking based on your words.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
var iframe    = document.getElementById('your-iframe-ID'), 
                /* or other kind of reference to the iframe DOM node */

    iframeDoc = ((!!iframe['contentDocument']) 
              ? iframe.contentDocument 
              : iframe.contentWindow.document),

    cell      = iframeDoc.getElementById('your-cell-ID');
                /* this is a reference to cell inside the iframe */
```

Of course I assume that `mainpage.html` and `back.html` are in the same domain (for the [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) policy)